# What is the best way to send a stream of data through a Socket?

Tags: c#, sockets

i made a program where there is some data that i want to send several times per second through a Socket. This code bellow (client side) works fine and its called 60 times per second, but i was thinking that maybe, close the socket every time i want to send some data is not the best option or it is inefficient. The problem is that until i dont close the socket, the server side dont read the data in the socket.

Client side in C# (the function Update is called several times per second):

```
void Update()
{


    soc = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);


    string server = "127.0.0.1";
    IPAddress ipAdd = IPAddress.Parse(server);
    
    IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAdd, 3456);

    soc.Connect(remoteEP);

    byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("velocidad(k/h): " + telemetria.vehicle.data.Get(Channel.Vehicle, VehicleData.Speed)*3.6f/1000.0f);

    soc.Send(msg);

    soc.Close();
}
```

Server side in Java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(3456);
    while(true) {
        Socket s = ss.accept();
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(in);
        String str = bf.readLine();
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using `readLine()` on the Java side but you're not sending lines on the C# side. Please read the documentation for [`readline`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) about what constitutes a *line*.

Comment: The best way is just to send it. When the user opens the program, create a socket and connect to the server. Then, whenever there is data to send, you just send it. When the user closes the program you close the socket. And yes, the reason you think you need to close is probably because you are trying to read a line.